# Calling all files within a folder in R

Tags: r, file

There is a folder that contains some files of interest. Using R, I want to call every file in the folder. I can do it individually for each file as follows:

```
source("filename.r")
```

But is there any way to specify all such files in the folder in one stroke?

Comment: see example at the bottom of `?source`

Comment: It worked, thanks a lot!

Answer (score -1):

I would use the `list.files()` command in combination with a `for` loop. Make sure you have set your working directory. You can also specify a directory in `list.files()`

```
Files<-list.files()
for(i in 1:length(Files))
{
assign(paste("File_",i,sep=""),read.csv(Files[i]))
}
```

Obviously, the second input in my assign function can differ depending on what type of files you are looking to call

Comment: The example at the botton of ?source helped me, but will keep this in mind too. Thanks!

Comment: Note that `paste0` is convenient shorthand for `paste(..., sep = "")`.